# Have I messed up my restful routes by using only post and get?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

After reading some article about Restful, I'm not too sure if I've used the correct paths and HTTP verbs for my routes. For example:

This is my route for displaying an image:

```
Route::get('/image/{id}', 'PagesController@specificImage')->name('specificImage');
```

and this is the route for deleting an image:

```
Route::get('/deleteImage/{id}', 'ArtworkController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
```

Would it be more correct to change the image deletion route to:

```
Route::delete('/image/{id}', 'ArtworkController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
```

I've changed the GET to DELETE and changed the path from `/deleteImage/{id}` to `/image/{id}`. I guess that makes more sense but I'm wondering whether there would be a conflict between the GET `/deleteImage/{id}` and the DELETE `/deleteImage/{id}`.

Is it safe to assume that the route for updating an image ( which will be added in the future ) should look something like this:

```
Route::patch('/image/{id}', 'ArtworkController@updateImage')->name('updateImage');
```

The other route which I think might be a bit incorrect is my route which used for making changes to your profile.

This route shows you the profile of a user:

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}', 'PagesController@profile')->name('profile');
```

and this route is used for making changes to a profile:

```
Route::patch('/profile/{user}/update', 'UsersController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

Since this route is using PATCH, can I remove the `/update` part of the path and still have it working even though it is the same path as the GET route which shows you the profile?

Essentially being able to use the same path for both getting, creating, updating and deleting and just changing the HTTP verb makes it so much better readability wise. I understand that I can use GET and POST only and still have everything working fine but I need to know if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In REST, URL should always contain path to the resource only.
You are not allowed to use verbs, only nouns.
Actions are performed on the resource using methods ( `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE` etc. ).

In your case, the resource is `image`, so the endpoint looks like:  `/images/{id}`.
To `delete` the image (resource): `DELETE` `/images/{id}`.
To replace the image (resource): `PUT` `/images/{id}`

The same story applies to account, resource is `/profile/{username}` in this case.
To update part of the profile ( eg. age ), use `PATCH` `/profile/{username}`.

Please note:
`PUT` is used to insert/replace the resource
`PATCH` is used to modify some of the attributes on the existing resource.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Laravel's standard way of handling CRUD routes, the changes you are making are partially correct.  You can actually have Laravel automatically generate standardized routes for you using `Route::resource`, but you would need to have all of the methods for working with your model in the same controller (e.g. `ImageController` for images).

```
Route::resource('images', 'ImageController');
```

You can do the command "php artisan route:list" in your command prompt or terminal to see what routes are generated by the Route::resource.  See [this article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) for more information.

Now, regarding your original question, the standards would be:

```
Route::get('images/{id}', 'ImageController@show') // to view the image
Route::get('images/create', 'ImageController@create') // to view the create new image page
Route::post('images', 'ImageController@store') // to store a new image
Route::get('images/{id}/edit', 'ImageController@edit') // to view the edit page
Route::patch('images/{id}', 'ImageController@update') // to save changes
Route::delete('images/{id}', 'ImageController@delete') // to delete
```

There will not be conflicts between routes using different methods that have the same URL.  You can have multiple routes that point to `images/{id}` as long as the methods are different.